# Text path with icon in the center elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I am trying to add an icon to the center of a circle text path in elementor to look something like the image below:

[image]

what could be the best way to do this in elementor using text path and icon?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Henry, you can easily do this by these step:**

1. Add an text path, make it into circle and set it size.
2. Add an icon, give it an ID and set it size, make it's position to absolute, set it's offset to half of circle size.
3. Add this CSS rule to the icon (the icon's ID is tho-icon and the icon size is 66px):

   ```
    #tho-icon{
    height: 66px;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
   }
   ```

**I have make a [short video guide here](https://youtu.be/1aQsydLSmKg) in case my instruction is not clearly**